# German chess composition glossary

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to look through some puzzles at http://www.wenigsteiner.de/, but there are some abbreviations I'm not familiar with that I'm having a hard time finding through Google; I guess they are abbreviations for German words, but I don't know German. Is there a glossary with such words?

In particular:

- I think VRZ just means defensive retractor, short for "Verteidigungsrückzüger", but what is VV VRZ? (Seen in Andreas Thoma's problems from 2018 preselection)
- What is kBP 22.0 (I'm guessing "shortest proof game", but I'm not sure how)? (Seen in the First Prize problem from 2018)

Answer (score 10):

VV is Vorwärtsverteidigung - if a position is retracted into where Black might interfere (by mating White himself ?!), he may. kbP is indeed SPG.
[A translation source for many problem chess terms](https://hilmar-alquiros.de/A.htm)

Comment: In particular, kBP stands for "kürzeste Beweispartie".

Answer (score 5):

The glossary at https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/keywords.jsp?s=all translates many terms from German, English & French. However it is far from complete.

For fairy terms there is also https://www.dieschwalbe.de/lexikon.htm

Any particular questions which remain, please raise here and I will try to answer.